# MySQL database connect: There is an error while processing this request

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am breaking my head why I cannot make a succesful database connection. When I am using the below code I get a blank page with this error: `500: There is an error while processing this request`. The dbname, username, code is 100% correct. If i just set in:`<?php echo "Hello World";?>` the page is working fine and echo out Hello World. So I guess it has to be something to do with my database connection code?

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

**index.php:**

```
<?php
include 'db_connection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
echo "Connected Successfully";
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

**db_connection.php:**

```
<?php
    function OpenCon()
     {
     $dbhost = "localhost";
     $dbuser = "root";
     $dbpass = "mycode";
     $db = "store";
     $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

     return $conn;
     }

    function CloseCon($conn)
     {
     $conn -> close();
     }

    ?>
```

**Image of the MySQL files:**
I am running the database in a Synology DS918 server. As I recall the log is under `/var/log/mysql/`. But I cannot find that path here. Does anybody knows where the log should lay?

[image]

Comment: check the server logs

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I just updated my answer with an image.

Comment: That's the path for the MySQL log. You want the PHP/webserver log for 500 errors.